# Require specific gem version in SASS & Compass

Tags: css, ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I know this is probably more a Ruby question but I work on several projects where I've used compass plugins. Later on I upgrade these plugins and start new projects. The issue arises when I need to go back and make amends to an older project.

How can I amend my config.rb file to use a specific version of a gem?

For example I often use the Compass plugin:  http://rubygems.org/gems/html5-boilerplate/versions

The line in my `config.rb` file looks like this:

```
require 'html5-boilerplate'
```

But I would need `1.0.0` for one project and `2.1.0` in another.

Comment: I found the solution...`gem "html5-boilerplate", "~> 2.1.0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest using [`rvm`](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) (the Ruby enVironment Manager), bundler and gemsets. `rvm` for managing ruby versions and for allowing you to use gemsets - bundler to specify the versions of the gems you want to use in the project. After you install the bundler gem and have a Gemfile that uses the syntax you have already discovered

```
gem "html5-boilerplate", "~> 2.1.0"
```

`bundle install` will then bring down the gems you need for your project.  Read more at http://gembundler.com

gemsets can also be project specific and different gemsets can have the same gems at different versions. you can specify the gemset associated with a project via a `.rvmrc` file in the project's root.

There are several nice posts out there on how to set up rvm and gemsets. Here's a good example of one to get you going:

http://adamstacoviak.com/posts/super-easy-ruby-gem-management-with-rvm-gemsets/

And here's one that also covers bundler:

http://lindsaar.net/2010/3/31/bundle_me_some_sanity